# ElasticSearch - Dynamic capacity

Tags: elasticsearch

i have three node elastic search cluster having 250 GB disk space on each one of them, I have three shards, one on each of them. If i run out of disk capacity and add another ( Fourth)  node with 500 GB disk will ElasticSearch cluster would move one of shard to avail of higher disk on fourth node ?

Comment: Only if you configured your index to be composed of 4 shards, so that each node gets a piece of the data.

Comment: Thanks Andrei for answering,,

Comment: I though ES can be smart to know that added node has higher storage capacity...and can move one hard out there. may be some other considerations.. It is not yet that dynamic..